# Centroid of a parabola with positive and negative areas

Tags: conic-sections, centroid

Consider the parabola $18x-3x^2-12$ (https://www.desmos.com/calculator/efel9y5dbj). It is required to find the centroid of this parabola contained between x=0 and x=2. For x=0 to x=0.764 its ordinates are negative and beyond x=0.764 the ordinates are positive. I considered the two areas separately and tried determining the centroid. However something is going wrong. The area enclosed between x=0 to x=0.764 is 4.3607 and the other area is 8.3607.

The centroid of area between x=0 to x=0.764 is,0.2481. The centroid of the other area is 1.5647, measured from the origin. When I use the formula for finding the centroid of composite sections, it gives a value of 3. But, it can't be correct as the parabola taken here has its domain limited to x=2. I am completely clueless about how to do it correctly.

Comment: Which areas do you have in mind? The concept of centroid of a line has nothing to do with areas. I did the computations, and I got the point $(0.835,0.015)$.

Comment: I mean, the centroid of the area under the given parabola between x=0 and x=2. The concern is not about finding the centroid of the line.

Comment: Usually, "under the given parabola" means "between the parabolic arc and the chord subtended to it".

Comment: Please excuse my ignorance. The intended area is shaded in https://www.desmos.com/calculator/bz9vjkablr.

Comment: $${0.2481\cdot4.3607 + 1.5647\cdot8.3607\over4.3607 + 8.3607}=1.1134$$

Comment: Thank you. I am not sure if a negative sign be considered for the region between x=0 to x=0.764. That is the main source of confusion.

Comment: You should edit your question to explain it in more detail. As written, it is misleading.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)=18x-3x^2-12$. First of all, the area $A$ of your region is
$$
\int_0^{3-\sqrt5}\int_{f(x)}^01\,dy\,dx+\int_{3-\sqrt5}^2\int_0^{f(x)}1\,dy\,dx=20\sqrt5-32.
$$
Now, the $x$-coordinate of the centroid is
\begin{align}
\frac1A\left(\int_0^{3-\sqrt5}\int_{f(x)}^0x\,dy\,dx+\int_{3-\sqrt5}^2\int_0^{f(x)}x\,dy\,dx\right)&=\frac{15}{61} \left(9-2 \sqrt{5}\right)\\
&\approx1.11341
\end{align}
and the $y$-coordinate of the centroid is
\begin{align}
\frac1A\left(\int_0^{3-\sqrt5}\int_{f(x)}^0y\,dy\,dx+\int_{3-\sqrt5}^2\int_0^{f(x)}y\,dy\,dx\right)&=\frac{6}{305} \left(209-60 \sqrt{5}\right)\\
&\approx1.47218.
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you very much. The obscurity arises because of the negative value the function can take between x=0 to x=0.76393. The context is, the given function is the loading on a simply supported beam.

Comment: In order to find the support reactions we need the total load and the centroid. If I consider both areas to be positive and do it the way you have done it, it essentially means a different kind of loading. That is, it would be the case where the entire loading is acting downwards over the entire span. But, what I am looking for is the case where for x=0 to x= 0.76393 the load acts upwards on the beam and for the remaining length it acts downwards. I must have already explained the complete background of the problem. Mistake is mine.

Comment: @LManimaran In that case your result $x=3$ is fine. But I wouldn't call that "the centroid of the parabola".